# Reading a string from an opened text file

Tags: python, string, file, text

The code below is supposed to iterate over various items in a text file and return true if their first and last characters are the saem. If I use a simple string saved as a variable in the code it works fine. However, as soon as I get it to check the same word from the text file it returns False even though the word is a palindrome. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
def is_palindrome(line):
    if line[0] == line[-1]:        
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
infile = open('palindrome_input.txt', 'r')

line = infile.readline()

is_palindrome(line)
```

Comment: you should include a tag for the programming language you are using, and format your code

Comment: My bad. It's python. It's formatted my code all wrong on here.